# EntityFramework 7 (EF7) Migrations. DbContext and StartUp Project are in different assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use migrations in EF7 with entityframework.commands. But my DbContext is in different assembly with Start-up project (asp.net mvc is an start-up project and Core.Implementation has a DbContex).

**dnx . ef migration add MyMigration -c MyContext**

*System.InvalidOperationException: No DbContext named 'MyContext' was found.*

I've tried to use namespace to point to other assembly but it didn't work either. Is it possible at all? Or I just have to put my context in assembly where ef7 command is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per issues [#639](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/639), [#2256](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2256), [#2293](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2293), [#2294](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2294), [#2357](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2357), [#2553](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2553) & [#2748](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2748), we have a bit of work to do in that area. :-)

Comment: Does anybody know any workaround that does not require to have the Entity DbContext in the same assembly as the Startup project (I guess you guys are working on a stable solution rather than workaround)? a parameter to target the ```MyContext``` project when executing the ef command would be nice :)

Comment: @realavaloro There is no obvious workaround. Per [#2748](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2748), DNX can't load assemblies if they're not referenced, and referencing your Startup project from your DbContext project would result in a circular dependency. :(

Comment: @bricelam Looks like the issues mentioned have been closed. Does this mean it is this now possible in EF7 RC1 without the workaround provided by @gisek? If so what is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: @neodymium See the [Design Meeting Notes for October 28, 2015](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(October-28,-2015))

Answer (score 23):

**EDIT**

Since 1.0.0-rc1-final (maybe earlier) this workaroud is unnecessary

- Now you don't need `App.DataAccess/Startup.cs` (just delete it if you used the workaround below)
- You create/execure migrations form your main project (in this case
  `App.Web`)
- However you have to specify the project (`-p` paramater) containing migrations:

---

```
cd App.Web
dnx ef migrations add NewMigration -p App.DataAccess
```

If you have multiple database contexts you also have to specify which one to use (`-c` parameter)

```
cd App.Web
dnx ef migrations add NewMigration -p App.DataAccess -c YourDbContext
```

**END OF EDIT**

I found out a workaround for that

Suppose you have 2 projects: `App.Web` and `App.DataAccess`

You can add a very basic Startup class to your `App.DataAccess`:

```
>App.Web
-->Startup.cs // your main startup
>App.DataAccess
-->path/to/ApplicationDbContext.cs
-->different/path/to/YourModels.cs
-->Startup.cs // add a simple startup class
-->project.json
```

The simple Startup class (`App.DataAccess\Startup.cs`):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.Logging;

namespace App.DataAccess
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("../App.Web/config.json"); // path to your original configuration in Web project

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Than modify your project.json in App.DataAccess (`App.DataAccess/project.json`):

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "App.DataAccess Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Author" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
  },

  "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands" // this line is important, it will give you access to 'dnx ef' in command line
  }
}
```

Tha all you have to do is go to `App.DataAccess` and use `dnx ef`:

```
cd App.DataAccess
dnx ef migrations add NewMigration
dnx ef migrations remove
dnx ef database update
dnx ef ...
```

Comment: This workaround worked perfectly for me. I'll need to revisit the code once the changes @bricelam has mentioned have been implemented but for now this works well.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using a Standard .Net Class Library (which is referenced by the asp.net 5 Web Application)
[I need to use a standard class library as T4 templating is not working in class library packages]

Comment: I am using  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },  will this work ? and what is the difference

Comment: @gisek How can you do this with dotnet and not dnx?

Comment: @Reft I didn't have much more time to put into it. So after migrating to ASP Core 1.0.0 I moved migrations folder to the web project (still keeping models and DbContext in a separate project). Than I run `dotnet ef migrations add migrationName -c ApplicationDbContext`. There may be a better way though, but like I said, I didn't have much time to explore it.

Comment: :( When I ran "dotnet ef migrations add migrationName -c TestContext" I got: "This version of the Entity Framework Core .NET Command Line Tools does not support commands on class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications."

Comment: You can find more about my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213583/net-core-entity-framework-add-migration-for-context-in-class-library

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core 1.0 and EF Core 1.0

Suppose we want to move our context to `Core1RtmEmptyTest.DataLayer` project.

First enable EF tools for this sub project by modifying its `project.json` file:

```
{
     // same as before

    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
            "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
            "imports": [
                "portable-net45+win8"
            ]
        }
    },

     // same as before
}
```

Then run the command from the root of this new project (and not from the root of the main project)

```
D:\path\Core1RtmEmptyTest\src\Core1RtmEmptyTest.DataLayer>dotnet ef --startup-project ../Core1RtmEmptyTest/ migrations add InitialDatabase
```

Here we should specify the `startup-project` too.

And finally to update the database

```
D:\path\Core1RtmEmptyTest\src\Core1RtmEmptyTest.DataLayer>dotnet ef --startup-project ../Core1RtmEmptyTest/ database update
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, but i'm using EFCore 1.0.0 so you must migrate. Below the codesnippets you need to make it work:

The idea is to have a central datacontext: `MigrationsDataContext` to handle whole database migrations. So you can place this migration in a separated project dedicated only for migrating database. You only must make `MigrationsDataContext` see others projects containing required datacontexts. This way, you can instantiate each other datacontext and call `OnModelCreating` method manually passing current DbContext's `ModelBuilder` as parameter.

```
public class MigrationsDataContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, DbContextOptions> dbCtxOpts;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> dbCtxTypes = new[] {
        typeof(CoreDataContext),
        typeof(DbContext1),
        typeof(DbContext2),
    };

    public MigrationsDataContext(DbContextOptions<MigrationsDataContext> options,
        IEnumerable<DbContextOptions> dbCtxOpts)
        :base(options)
    {
        this.dbCtxOpts = dbCtxOpts
            .GroupBy(o => o.ContextType)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
    }

    public MigrationsDataContext()
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        foreach (var db in dbCtxTypes.Select(t => new { Type = t, Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t, dbCtxOpts[t]) }))
        {
            var configurator = db.Type.GetMethod(nameof(OnModelCreating), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            configurator.Invoke(db.Instance, new[] { builder });
        }
    }
}
```

In Order to Receive all DbContextOptions from constructor, you meed to register the whole bundle of `DbContextOptions<T>` as `DbContextOptions` this is achieved by calling the following method in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddBundle<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var baseType = typeof(T);

        var bundle = services
            .Where(d => baseType.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(d.ServiceType))
            .Select(d => d.ServiceType)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var ctxType in bundle)
            services.AddScoped(baseType, s => s.GetService(ctxType));

        return services;
    }
```

`Startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<CoreDataContext>(ConfigEf)
            .AddDbContext<DbContext1>(ConfigEf)
            .AddDbContext<DbContext2>(ConfigEf)
            .AddDbContext<MigrationsDataContext>(ConfigEf)
            .AddBundle<DbContextOptions>()
            .AddBundle<DbContext>();
...
```

That's all. Now you manage migrations this way:

move to you Migrations project, adjacent to MyWebApp project,

```
`$> dotnet ef --startup-project ../MyWebApp migrations add Initial --context Migrations.MigrationsDataContext`
```

Hope this help.