# A type named 'StartupDevelopment' or 'Startup' could not be found in assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have separated my database access logic in an ASP.NET 5 Class Library project. When I try to generate migrations running **dnx ef migrations add Initial** I get the error message **"A type named 'StartupDevelopment' or 'Startup' could not be found in assembly..."**. I don't want to move my database logic back into the web project. I have referenced "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-15865" and "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-15865".

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870709/entityframework-7-ef7-migrations-dbcontext-and-startup-project-are-in-differe

Comment: @DavidTansey, that helps. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome - #SOreadytohelp

Comment: @DavidTansey please consider adding that as an answer so this question doesn't remain unanswered

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870709/entityframework-7-ef7-migrations-dbcontext-and-startup-project-are-in-differe