# Can't add Entity Framework migrations when project is split

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am porting a project from MVC 5 to MVC 6. My project has two components the MVC application itself and a assembly that has all of the database code in it, including all db models, and the `DbContext`.

In the assembly I modified the `project.json` to have the ef commands dll and removed it from the MVC `project.json`. I have ported over all of my models, etc. and the application is compiling without errors.  I want to execute

```
dnx ef migrations add
```

from a command shell in the subdirectory of the assembly in the project. When I do that I get

> No DbContext was found. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

What is the correct way to accomplish this type of project organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your run this command from the `project.json` that has your EF Commands and your DBContext. You will not be able to run this from the `artifacts` folder since dnx custom commands like `ef` are registered on a per `project.json` basis.

If you are not already on the latest beta, it would be a good opportunity to try it again on `beta8` to make sure everything works.

PS: Not just `dnvm upgrade` but the [tooling](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442) as well.

If nothing works, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799213/24975) other question. You will need a Startup.cs but it doesn't need to run anything in particular. It just need able to configure the dependencies.

Comment: I am using beta8.  I have two projects, one MVC, and one a plain assembly called "repository".  The ef commands assembly is in the "Repository" assembly.  I run the command from "Repository" assembly directory.  and it gives the error message "A type named 'StartupDevelopment' or 'Startup' could not be found in assembly 'STOrm.Repository'.".  If I run it from the MVC project it gives the error in my original post.  Not sure how to make this work.  This same scenario works in EF6.

Comment: Updated my answer with info from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32799213/24975

Comment: that solved the issue.  It makes complete sense now although it is kind of weird if you ask me

Comment: It is weird but [they are aware of the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2256). It seems closed but they have multiple issues tracking this scenario and other scenarios.