# .NET Core Entity Framework - Add migration for Context in class library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having problems adding an initial migration to my Entity Framework database context inside a .NET Core class library.

When I run:

```
dotnet ef migrations add migrationName -c PlaceholderContext
```

I get error:

```
Could not invoke this command on the startup project 'Placeholder.Data'. This version of the Entity Framework Core .NET Command Line Tools does not support commands on class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and workarounds.
```

So I clicked on the [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221) and learned that it's not possible to add a migration to a class library. You can however convert the class library project into an "app" project but by doing so I can not reference this "app" project from my business layer (class library).

**Project structure:**

**Placeholder.Web** (WebAPI) => **Placeholder.Business** (class library) => **Placeholder.Data** (class library)

[image: Project structure]

**Placeholder.Web => Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();

        //HERE WE REGISTER DB CONTEXT, (STATIC CLASS IN BUSINESS LAYER)
        services.InjectBusinessContext(@"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=Placeholder;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

        services.InjectWebServices();
        services.InjectBusinessServices();
    }
```

How can I overcome this really annoying problem?

**Update (1)**

I have converted my Placeholder.Data class library to an "app" with a static main method. Because I can no longer reference Placeholder.Data from Placeholder.Business I have to go with workaround 2 listed on the microsoft doc page. When I now run the migration script I get the following:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a 
>           DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext

Doh ofcourse this wont work, the dbcontext is registered from my Placeholder.Web app, (through business layer). Then my only option is to add a new context in the new static main method and I dont really want to do this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to 'convert' your data project to an app. Here is a test app with a similar structure:

[image: project structure]

In the project.json in the Data project, add the asp.net core nuget packages.

[image: project.json]

Now, to create a migration, just right click on the Data project, choose 'Open folder in file explorer,' then in file explorer, press Shift + right click and 'Open command window here.'

To create the migration, just specify the 'startup project' as the web app (where the startup.cs exists)

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../TestPatterns2.Web migrations add Second
```

[image: migrations]

And voila, migration:

[image: second migration]

TO ADD THE MIGRATION FOLDER INTO THE DATA PROJECT:
when you defined the service, add the migration point like so

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("TestPatterns2.Data")));
```

Comment: I'll try this later when i get home!

Comment: please mark as answer if it works for you. if you want to take this a step further, you can also extend IServiceCollection in your DATA class library project and add the DI and the connection strings in there so that your Web project will be totally independent of the DATA project.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, just tried your code and it works, cheers. But! If you look at my project structure I have a self-created folder named migrations. When I run the command I get a new migration folder in my root? 1. Can i change this? 2. If I want to add more migrations after first initial migration, do i need to follow these steps again or can create it the normal way with package manager console?

Comment: 1) yes you may, updated the answer to show how to do this   2) if you want to add more migrations, you simply run the dotnet ef command via the command line and specify a new migration name. You cannot run migrations via Package Manager Console in ASP.NET Core - it has to be via the CLI

Comment: sorry for nagging. It seems like its something wrong with the MigrationsAssembly parameter. I get: Your target project 'Placeholder.Data' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'Placeholder.Data/Database/Migrations', (I changed the MigrationsAssembly to 'Placeholder.Data/Database/Migrations'. If I just use Placeholder.Data it works)

Comment: You need to add the --output-dir <path> in the dotnet ef command to specify your output directory.

Comment: I think this is what I need.  I was struggling with this going through this article I was going to use as a starting point for my generic repo:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generic-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/.
Posted about this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281896/how-do-i-use-dotnet-migrations-in-net-core-when-my-model-and-repository-are-in.
I posted what I had to do but this looks like the more correct way.  My way was to convert back to EF Core 1.0.1 from 1.1.0.

Comment: @Sam glad that this worked. Upvote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

It only needs to be an app for making the migration (needs an entry point) so after making the library an app and creating your migration, comment out the `buildOptions` and `runtimes` elements in your project.json. It will now build as a library again.

Uncomment them whenever you need to add another migration.

Comment: I've tried converting from "netstandard1.6" to "netcoreapp1.0" but I'm getting .Data is not compatible with netstandard1.6.

Comment: Ok, I had to unload Business layer, (reference) and then it worked. I converted the class library to an app. Because I cant reference .Data from .Business I'm forced to go with Workaround 2. It seems like I need to register the context using main method in .Data? I dont want to do this..

Comment: @Reft The solution I used was to declare a DBFactory for it instead. I don't remember the blog post I found to do it though, sorry.